# What is wrong with this C function? (printf() with getchar())

Tags: c, printf, warnings, getchar

```
printf( "%3o\t%2x\t%3d\t%c\n", c = getchar(), c, c, c );
```

I'm getting a warning that says "unsequenced modification and access to 'c' [-Wunsequenced]".  The error is fairly easy to fix; all I have to do is separate `getchar()` from `printf()`, but I just want to have a better understanding of why this instruction is producing a warning, and what would go wrong if I actually ran it.

Does this have anything to do with the implementation of `printf()` using CPP macros for the variable-length argument list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The order in which arguments passed to a function call are evaluated is **unspecified**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order). There is no guarantee that the result of `getchar()` will be assigned to `c` before the last three `c` arguments are read.

Calling `c = getchar()` outside of the function call fixes the issue.